# Getting BSONArray from BSONElement in an direct way

Tags: c++, mongodb

`BSONElement` class has an `embeddedObject()` method to return `BSONObj` "encoded" in the BSON element, e.g:

```
// being 'be' a BSONElement object
BSONObj b = be.embeddedObject();
```

However, sometimes the `BSONElement` object encodes a `BSONArray` (a derived class from `BSONObj`) and I would like to get it directly. Something like

```
// being 'be' a BSONElement object
BSONArray b = be.embeddedArray();
```

but I haven't find an `embeddedArray()` or similar in [the MongoDB C++ driver documentation reference that I know](http://api.mongodb.org/cxx/legacy-1.0.7/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_element.html).

I have found an `Array()` method in `BSONElement` class, but it returns `std::vector<BSONElement>` and composing the equivalent `BSONArray` based on vector content would be much more complicated (taking into account that each element in the vector could be of different kind, i.e. strings, numbers, other BSON objects or arrays, etc.).

Is there any way of getting the BSONArray "encoded" in a `BSONElement` in an direct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that casting to `BSONArray` may work, in the following way:

```
BSONArray b = (BSONArray) be.embeddedObject();
```

This cast is unsafe in the general case, but combined with `type()` we can ensure that `be` is actually holding an embedded array.

However, I'm still wondering if a smarter way is possible... Feel free to add new answer to this question with alternative means, please.